# I'm trying to upload a screenshot to my app and I'm having an issue (app store connect)

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a screenshot to my app and I'm having an issue (app store connect).
Notably, I have some apps in the past that I managed to upload screenshots for App Previews and Screenshots. And now I can't.
I get this message when I try: Invalid GeoJSON: Your routing app coverage file is invalid. For more information, see the Location and Maps Programming Guide. "

The problem

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I changed the browser and its work..